# check validation guard inside function

Tags: ios, swift, guard

How to validate the guard inside var declaration

```
    var completionTime: DateComponents{

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"
        let selectedDateTime = mergeDateTime()
        guard selectedDateTime != "" else {
            return // return completionTime.self

        }
// Do your Stuff
    return differencesInDays

}
```

The above variable return the completion time difference input to Current date time

If user failed to enter date input date, I am validating the with guard should return here what?

Answer (score 1):

The usual thing is to use an Optional so you can return nil on failure.

```
var completionTime: DateComponents? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"
    let selectedDateTime = mergeDateTime()
    guard selectedDateTime != "" else {
        return nil
    }
    // Do your Stuff
    return differencesInDays
}
```

Comment: Nil is incompatible with return type 'DateComponents'

Comment: That is why I made it an Optional. Do you see?